# SonataAdminBundle form field query

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

In SonataAdminBundle in Admin class I cannot make an [orderBy on ManyToMany field](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/328).

For example Author and Book. Author can have many books, as well as Book can have many Autors. In link above it is written that I can use a query for a form field. So I could prepare a query that would select authors and irder them by name. How to manage this? How to get EntityManager there in order to create query and pass it through query option?

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('author', 'sonata_type_model', array('query' => ....), array('edit' => 'inline'))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I got it work:

```
/**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $entity = new \MyCompany\MyProjectBundle\Entity\Seria();
    $query = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager($entity)->createQuery('SELECT s FROM MyCompany\MyProjectBundle\Entity\Seria s ORDER BY s.nameASC');

    $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('seria', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => true, 'query' => $query), array('edit' => 'standard'))
        ->add('description', 'textarea',
               array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce'), 'required' => false))        
    ;
}
```

Comment: Take care, with recent version of Sonata, you need to set argument to getEntityManager(), like that: $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('MyCompany\MyProjectBundle\Entity\Seria')->createQuery('SELECT s FROM MyCompanyMyProjectBundle:Seria s ORDER BY s.name ASC');

Comment: It works with sf2.3 ? I obtained this error: Class does not exist" at /home/marc/work/play4fun/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 199

Comment: Thank you for `attr`. Where is the documentation about available formMapper field options ?

Answer (score 2):

Anything changed about that ? i'm getting a "class does not exist (500 error)" by using this.

Note : it was working back in Symfony 2.1 but not anymore in Symfony 2.2.

Comment: Works for me like this in Symfony 2.2

`$query_user = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User')->createQueryBuilder()
        ->add('select', 'u')
        ->add('from', 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User u')
        ->add('orderBy', 'u.username ASC');

$formMapper
            ->add('title',null,array('required' => true))
            ->add('user', null, array('required' => true, 'query_builder' => $query_user))
        ;`

Comment: Thank you, your code provided me the solution that it was not the modelManager or EntityManager who was causing this bug but inside entity. :)